# In the Esaki diode, how can one be 100% sure that there are tunnelling electrons with lower energy in comparison with the barrier's energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiconductor-physics, quantum-tunneling

In the tunnel diode, if it is all about the statistical accumulation/distribution, how can one be certain that there are electrons with lower energy (in comparison with the barrier's energy) which cross the barrier?

How do physicists "know" that it is not only the electrons (with higher energy) which cross the barrier?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141808/discussion-on-question-by-iv-nik-in-the-esaki-diode-how-can-one-be-100-sure-th).

Comment: in case this diode comes up in a search here is book on diodes https://books.google.gr/books?hl=en&lr=&id=svYkEAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA3&dq=Sze+SM+and+Ng+KK+(2007)+Physics+of+Semiconductor+Devices,+3rd+edn.+Wiley.&ots=K9Iv2YEX2E&sig=6uNV5DhpSkdQX-KoKTW_wo75cFA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 1):

This is meant to compliment the answer from anna v. From this reference: https://ecstudiosystems.com/discover/textbooks/basic-electronics/diodes/tunnel-diodes/

> [image]

This image contains all the proof. In Regions 1 through 2, electrons have passed through a narrow depletion region without loss of energy and at potentials lower than the barrier height. Also barrier width is as important (if not more so) as barrier height. In the Esaki diode tunneling occurs through a barrier width that is extremely thin at zero bias. An applied potential can also change this width.

The paper I have referenced is a nice overview.

Answer (score 0):

this is an extended comment :

Solid state is modeled with quantum mechanics. Quantum mechanics is all about probability distributions, so it has to be accumulation of statistics. The quantum mechanical barrier tunneling in a simple case :

[image: tunneling]

> [According to classical physics,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/barr.html) a particle of energy E less than the height U0 of a barrier could not penetrate - the region inside the barrier is classically forbidden. But the wavefunction associated with a free particle must be continuous at the barrier and will show an exponential decay inside the barrier. The wavefunction must also be continuous on the far side of the barrier, so there is a finite probability that the particle will tunnel through the barrier.

> As a particle approaches the barrier, it is described by a free particle wavefunction. When it reaches the barrier, it must satisfy the Schrodinger equation

(see the link for the mathematics).

In the case of the solid lattice things are more complicated but the concept is the same.

Comment: I clearly see that quantum tunneling is used as an "explanation". And it is "useful" model as far as the assumptions/beliefs "agree" with the average (of the experimental results). What is not clear is how one can be 100% certain that there is even one electron (with energy lower than the barrier's energy) which passes through the barrier. Also, a question-and-answer site is not one that is about copy-paste of information from Wikipedia and Hyperphysics, let alone to consider the copy-paste as "extended comment".

Comment: I copy pasted to show the figure that cannot be seen in a comment. Lets end this here.